# How do i change font of MDDataTable in KivyMD?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I tried many ways

```
def set_toolbar_font_name(self, *args):
     self.data_tables.table_data.font_name = "./fonts/Shivaji01.ttf"
```

but none of them are working !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set external fonts for tables using the `font_name` attribute. Just use markup for table rows - https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.text.markup.html

```
[font=<str>]Added in 1.1.0[/font]
    Change the font (note: this refers to a TTF file or registered alias)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but after using tags it is printing tags also instead of changing font ! can you please give me an example where i better understand your solution!

Comment: Update KivyMD library from master branch.

Comment: Last version is `0.104.2.dev0`